# Building a website with "catalogue" pages

Tags: database

I want to build a website that has the ability to search for products based on certain criteria.

Websites like Newegg.com are a perfect example.

What I want is the part that allows the website to list the products on the website dynamically on its pages and if there are too many products to list it will create pages(1,2,3).

I want to find some resources onto how to do this kind of stuff but can't formulate my question right to find it. What are some of the good resources? Complete beginner, never done this.

For a beginner would you suggest using ASP.NET for such kind of task?

Comment: What programming languages do you already know?

Comment: Well it's not that I know them but I've gotten my feet wet in the following languages: C#.NET, VB.NET, DHTML, XML(its not really a programming language but anyways), PHP, SQL, Oracle, ASP.NET, C++(little console experience). By no means I'm professional at any of them but I did try them all out. with c# and vb.net I've made a couple of programs that were handling database records(add, delete, edit, search, filte, sort, export in xml were some of the functionalities). I've made quiet a bunch of websites but they weren't javasciprt intense if not at all just static pages for personal hobby.

Comment: Then use whichever one you want to become more proficient in. Personally, I would never voluntarily use PHP, so I'd choose ASP.NET instead, but either stack is completely sufficient. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to use PHP and MYSQL, it's easier and there are a lot of ressources and examples.

Comment: Please substantiate your answer. "It's easier" is nothing but a matter of opinion. As for documentation, there's plenty of documentation for ASP.NET as well.

Answer (score 0):

I will not suggest any programming languages. Which one is easier, is an matter of opinion and perspective. Its up to each developer to draw his own conclusion.

But for a new developer you should probably leverage some existing solutions. Look for a  cms solutions (content management  system) like joomla, that  already have a solution for a use case like catalog listing.(Looking for samples will help)

For you to come up with a good enterprise solution, you need to optimize data store, have some mechanism like Lucene searching to enable faster searching experience and the complexity does not stop there. ( no matter what language you use)..